# וכתוב לחיים טובים כל-בני בריתך - addition for 10 days of teshuva

Tags: tefilla, aseres-yemei-teshuva, nusach-edot-hammizrach

In Nusach Edot haMizrach, we say וכתוב לחיים טובים כל-בני בריתך between וכל החיים יודוך סלה And ויהללו ויברכו...

Is there a source explaining why we put it there, instead of before וכל, and why this makes sense as a sentence?